# How to add HTML element that doesn't get parsed until later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I'm making a webpage and want to show a preloader before loading the rest of it. I want only my first `<head>` tag to be parsed by the browser and the rest to be ignored. This would be ideal:

```
<head>  
  <script src='preloader.js'></script>  
  <script src='more1.js' ignore='true'></script>  
  <script src='more2.js' ignore='true'></script>  
  <script src='more3.js' ignore='true'></script>  
</head>
```

This drove me to wonder how it might be possible to have existing, latent HTML tags on my page, that I mark later by JavaScript to activate them, like uncommenting them. I was thinking commented code would be the answer, but I wasn't able to read my HTML comments from jQuery's DOM.

How can I create latent HTML that I activate later?

I'm not looking to:
 - Have valid HTML.
 - Inject HTML content residing outside of its own file (changing stuff, like an attribute would be ok).
 - Unhide anything that has already been parsed.

Comment: Side note: don't you think that "Loading..." messages are the new Flash intros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to clarify a little bit: do you want the HTML to not be parsed or not be displayed?

If you don't want it to be parsed, plunk it in a JavaScript string in a script element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

var yourHTML = '<div id="whatever">...</div>';

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

If you don't want it to be displayed, set `display:none` on the **inline** styles (this prevents any issues that may happen with css):

```
<div id="whatever" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

In either case you can access the node later with jQuery using `$(yourHTML)` and `$('#whatever')` respectively.

Comment: hence the script tag. the HTML will be stored in the variable, but you can keep the script tag with the rest of the HTML.

Comment: How do I later uncomment the CDATA element?

Comment: @Pup after reading your updates, I see that you're really just looking for some `no-parsing` attribute, which does not exist, as it would need to be *parsed* to detect the attribute. It also looks like you want to dynamically add external scripts after the page has loaded.  No matter what you choose, you'll end up needing to use JavaScript to enable/detect/select/add/parse whatever html you want shown.

Comment: @Pup you don't. you add the contents of the `yourHTML` variable to the DOM with jQuery: `$(yourHTML).appendTo('#someElementID');` and voila! your html is on the page. I think you need to spend some more time reading about HTML & JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have the content added to the dom using javascript.

Since you are using jquery, you could do:

```
var aThingToAddLater = $('<div class="myNewDiv">div content</div>');

$("body").append(aThingToAddLater); // <-- this will add it to the dom, specifically as the last element of the body
```

This way, the actual 'unparsed-until-later' content would be javascript code.

Comment: Don't want to store the HTML outside of its own file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think you're doing it right, if you need a preloader for your web page. But then again, I do not know the entire context, and there might be cases where a preloader could be justified.

Have you tried simply setting display to none, and then showing the code when the page is ready? E.g.

```
<div class="preloader">...</div>
<div class="main" style="display: none">...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".main").show();
    });
</script>
```

If you want this work correctly you probably also need to flush the webserver's output buffer after the preloader-div has been sent. In PHP it would look like this:

```
<div class="preloader">...</div>
<?php
    flush();
?>
...
```